# Why are these two numbers comparing equal?

Tags: c++

I'm wondering why it's the case that these two numbers are comparing equal. I had a (maybe false) realisation that I messed up my enums, because in my enums I often do:

```
enum class SomeFlags : unsigned long long { ALL = ~0, FLAG1 = 1, FLAG2 };
```

And I thought that 0 being an int and being assigned to an unsigned long long, that there was a mistake.

```
unsigned long long number1 = ~0;
/* I expect the 0 ( which is an int, to be flipped, which would make it
the max value of an unsigned int. It would then get promoted and be 
assigned that value to an unsigned long long. So number1 should
have the value of max value of unsigned int*/



int main()
{
    unsigned long long number2 = unsigned long long(0);
    number2 = number2 - 1;
    /* Here I expect number2 to have the max value of unsigned long long*/

    if (number1 == number2)
    {
        std::cout << "Is same\n";
        // They are the same, but how???
    }
}
```

This is really confusing. To emphasise the point:

```
unsigned long long number1 = int(~0);
/* I feel like I'm saying:
- initialize an int with the value of zero with its bits flipped
- assign it to the unsigned long long

And this somehow ends up as the max value of unsigned long long???*/
```

Comment: The numbers have the same bit pattern as result. All bits set. Both are -1, but because of unsigned they are interpreted as unsigned long long max. And hence the same. Sorry, I maybe miss the point here.

Comment: It is because the `int` is converted to `long long` before being converted to `unsigned long long`.

Comment: `enum class …` is pure C++ and not C.

Comment: I suggest you print out your numbers on console and look up the definition for the ~ operator in C.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Bitwise_logic_operators): "*The result of `operator~` is the bitwise NOT (one's complement) value of the argument (after promotion.*"

No promotion (to `int` or `unsigned int`) is however needed here - but flipping all bits in a `signed` type with the value `0` will make it `-1` (all bits set) which when converted to an `unsigned` type will be the largest value that type can hold.

To avoid this, make `0` `unsigned`. The result of `~0U` will be an `unsigned int` with all bits set, which can be converted to any larger `unsigned` type perfectly.

```
unsigned long long number1 = ~0U;
```

Comment: I think the right hand side expression is evaluated first before the promotion happening during the assignment. Am I wrong about this?

Comment: Consider `unsigned long long a = INT_MAX + 1`, if promotion is to be occurred on the right hand side first. The result would have been 2147483548. However, the result shown on my c++ compiler is 18446744071562067968, which is the -1 equivalent in `unsigned long long`. So I don't see how promotion will occurred on the RHS expression first.

Comment: @LearningMathematics The promotion is to `int` or `unsigned int` (before `~`) is applied - but that's not needed here (since it's already `int`) - so my wording was incorrect. It's not avoiding promotion. Using an `unsigned` mearly makes the result of flipping the bits an `unsigned int` too which can be perfectly represented in an `unsigned long`. I updated it a bit.

Answer (score 3):

You seems to be thinking that the conversion of `int` to `long long` is done just by prepending 0 in front of the `int`. While this is true for the conversion of positive integer, it's not true for negative integers.

```
unsigned long long number1 = ~0
```

is identical as

```
unsigned long long number1 = -1
```

So when the conversion takes place, it is not simply copying the bits into `number1`

Answer (score 3):

Since C++11 unsigned arithmetic must use modulo wrapping.

Which means that if you have N bits then any operation OP works like this:

```
result = (a OP b) % (2^N)
```

Say you have 8 bits and substract as operation.

```
unsigned char result1 = (0 - 1) % 256 = -1 % 256 = 255 = 0b11111111
unsigned char result2 = ~(0b00000000) = 0b11111111 = 255
```

The same holds for larger N and thus your result

Answer (score 2):

In C/C++ integer promotion is governed by the type of the SOURCE argument, not the DESTINATION.

So - the promotion from signed integer types will be sign extended - regardless the type of the destination, be it signed or unsigned.

The promotion from unsigned integer types will be zero extended - again, regardless the type of destination.

In your case 0 is signed integer and ~0 is also signed integer. This will be sign extended to unsigned long long.

Answer (score 1):

The conversion from `int` to `unsigned long long` is specified based on the *value* of the `int` (aka "the source integer") not the bit pattern.  The value is -1 in this case:

> 4.7 Integral conversions [conv.integral]
>
> A prvalue of an integer type can be converted to a prvalue of another integer type. A prvalue of an unscoped enumeration type can be converted to a prvalue of an integer type.
>
> If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source integer (modulo 2^n where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type). [ Note: In a two’s complement representation, this conversion is conceptual and there is no change in the bit pattern (if there is no truncation). — end note ]

For an integer with a value of -1 the "least unsigned integer congruent to the source integer" modulo 2^64 is (-1 + 2^64).

The simple-to-understand effect of this rule is that `int` is sign-extended when being converted to an unsigned type.

Comment: Note: there's no "promotion to int" happening - `~0` is already an int.  It happens to have the value -1, so the conversion from a negative integer value to an unsigned value is taking place with the whole "least unsigned integer congruent..." thing.  As @TedLyngmo suggested, forcing that expression to be unsigned will get you the behavior you expected.  In that case the integer value being 'converted' is a large positive number, and it turns out that the "least unsigned integer congruent to the source integer" is that value unchanged.